# Python - Extend data frame by differences for numeric columns with split by unique IDs

Tags: python, list, append, apply, pandas-groupby

I would like to add calculated differences to existing dataframe in reference to IDs.  Differences were saved to separate data frame.

Actual dataFrame has the following view `df1`:

```
 Id   Col1   Col2  Col3
 567   6       7    9
 567   8       10   18 
 567   9       11   20  
 567   10      12   30   
 567   4       16   57
 ...   ...     ...  ...
 1568   6       7     9
 1568   8       10   18 
 1568   9       11   20  
 1568   10      12   30   
 1568   4       16   57
```

Calculated differences saved to `df2` for each Id separately, for example for `Id=567`:

```
 Col1_d1  Col2_d1   Col3_d1
  NaN       NaN       NaN
  -2        -3        -9 
  -1        -1        -2  
  -1        -1        -10   
   6        -4        -27
```

Also, `NaN`values I filled by `0`.

I tried to use `groupby` and `map`, but there is no success.

`L1 = [x for _, x in df1.groupby(df1['Id'])]`

How I can merge it with my second dataFrame `df2` in view of the required grouping by `Id`?

I tried to do it by: `list(map(lambda x: df1.append(x), L1))`

Expected result:

```
 Id   Col1   Col2  Col3  Col1_d1  Col2_d1   Col3_d1
 567   6       7    9      0          0        0
       8       10   18     -2        -3        -9 
       9       11   20     -1        -1        -2 
       10      12   30     -1        -1        -10    
       4       16   57      6        -4        -27
 1568  6       7    9       0         0        0
       8       10   18     -2        -3        -9 
       9       11   20     -1        -1        -2 
       10      12   30     -1        -1        -10    
       4       16   57      6        -4        -27
```

I appreciate for any idea and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by usage:

```
 df1.reset_index(inlace = True)
 df2['index'] = df1['index']
 dfList = [df1, df2]
 reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'index'), dfList)
```